# How to remove a row from table with typescript angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am building a To-Do application, and want to remove a row when I click the button.

This is my table HTML:

```
<table *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index;" class="todo {{(todo.completed ? 'done' : '')}}" >
  <!-- Position Column -->

  <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left;">{{i+1}}</td>


  <!-- Name Column -->


  <td style="width: 80%;text-align: left;" (dblclick)="toggleDone(i)">{{todos[i].content}}</td>


  <!-- Weight Column -->


  <td style="width: 10%;text-align: left;">
    <button class="delete" mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteTodo(i)">Sil</button>
  </td>

</table>
```

This is my `deleteTodo` method. I get the console message with the right index but it won't delete from the table:

```js
deleteTodo(id:number){
    this.todos=this.todos.splice(id,1);
    console.log(id +"silindi");
```

Comment: Instead of writing `class="todo {{(todo.completed ? 'done' : '')}}"`, do it like this: `class="todo" [class.done]="todo.completed"`.

Comment: Why are you rendering a table for each Todo. Please learn basics of (semantic) HTML, this should be a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes you need to do:

CSS - Use classes instead of placing all the styles on the elements:

```
.position {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
}
    
.name {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
}
    
.weight {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <!-- The ngFor should be on the tr (table row) element, not the table element. Same goes for the "todo" and "done" classes -->
    <tr *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index;" class="todo" [class.done]="todo.completed">
        <td class="position">{{i+1}}</td>

        <!-- Use todo instead of todos[i] -->
        <td class="name" (dblclick)="toggleDone(i)">{{todo.content}}</td>

        <td class="weight">
            <button class="delete" mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteTodo(i)">Sil</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

TypeScript in your component:

```
deleteTodo(id: number) {
    this.todos.splice(id, 1);
    this.todos = [...this.todos];
    console.log(id +"silindi");
}
```

Comment: Did not work at all

Comment: Can you elaborate? Did you replace your code with the above code in the right places? HTML code should go to your html file, the styles should go to you css file or the inline styles entry in your component, and the deleteTodo code should be in your component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
deleteTodo(id:number){
   const deletedElemnt = this.todos.splice(id,1);
   console.log(id +"silindi");
   console.log("deleted row: ", deletedElemnt );
   console.log("todos list: ", this.todos );
}
```

The **this.todos.splice(id,1) operation** was deleting the desired row, but **at the same time was returning the deleted element**.

You were assigning that returned element to your whole list of todos, so finally **your 'todos' list were just 1 row, the deleted element**.

Comment: it didnt work it changed the içerik of the 0 index